# Fix mod_pagespeed Fetch timed out error on bitnami AWS wordpress installation

Tags: php

My site isn't loading.

I'm getting the following errors in /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log -

```
[Thu Mar 09 18:43:49.420787 2017] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 1549:tid 140430532409088] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @1549] Fetch timed out: http://ourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ourdomain_page_3.jpg-200x200.jpg (connecting to:172.31.7.85) (1) waiting for 50 ms
[Thu Mar 09 18:43:49.583085 2017] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 2201:tid 140430112970496] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @2201] Fetch timed out: http://ourdomain.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/js/layerslider.transitions.js?ver=5.6.9 (connecting to:172.31.7.85) (1) waiting for 50 ms
[Thu Mar 09 18:43:49.584180 2017] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 1548:tid 140430381405952] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @1548] Fetch timed out: http://ourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/thefox/js/custom_woo_js.js?ver=4.6.1 (connecting to:172.31.7.85) (1) waiting for 50 ms
```

I've tried restarting it and the site runs for a moment.

It looks like php-fpm is hogging lots of resources -

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-7-85:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs$ ps aux --sort -rss
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
daemon    2055  4.7 12.8 1424768 262208 ?      Sl   17:05   4:56 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
mysql     1478  5.2 10.8 1394972 222988 ?      Sl   16:46   6:31 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql --datadir=/opt/bitnami/mysq
daemon    1548  2.0  8.2 1343136 168388 ?      Sl   16:46   2:30 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    1984  2.1  7.4 1309288 152796 ?      Sl   17:01   2:19 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    1550  1.7  7.1 1310236 147188 ?      Sl   16:46   2:08 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    1787  2.3  7.1 1310972 146572 ?      Sl   16:46   2:54 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    2201  2.5  7.0 1310088 145388 ?      Sl   17:15   2:22 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    2275  1.7  7.0 1308464 144508 ?      Sl   17:23   1:30 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    1549  1.6  6.6 1310164 136604 ?      Sl   16:46   2:04 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
daemon    1533  4.6  2.6 284192 54868 ?        R    16:46   5:41 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1968  8.6  2.6 286704 54032 ?        R    16:52  10:08 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1952  8.5  2.6 284464 54016 ?        R    16:48  10:22 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1957  8.5  2.6 284580 53944 ?        R    16:49  10:18 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1959  8.6  2.6 284396 53608 ?        R    16:51  10:12 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1857  8.4  2.5 287104 53156 ?        R    16:46  10:24 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1967  4.5  2.5 286500 51572 ?        R    16:52   5:22 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1965  8.6  2.4 284332 50612 ?        R    16:52  10:12 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1963  5.3  2.4 284072 49560 ?        R    16:52   6:21 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
daemon    1961  8.6  2.2 283264 46092 ?        R    16:52  10:12 php-fpm: pool wordpress                                                                                                             
root      1543  0.0  1.0 206004 22444 ?        Ss   16:46   0:03 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -DDISABLE_BANNER
root      1531  0.0  0.3 264860  7096 ?        Ss   16:46   0:01 php-fpm: master process (/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.conf)                                                                         
root      1902  0.0  0.2 200460  4636 ?        Ssl  16:46   0:00 /usr/bin/gonit
root      2452  0.0  0.2 105640  4216 ?        Ss   18:43   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
bitnami   2462  0.0  0.1  22412  3716 pts/0    Ss   18:43   0:00 -bash
root       981  0.0  0.1   9472  3448 ?        Ss   16:46   0:04 /usr/sbin/haveged -w 1024
root      2488  0.0  0.1  62720  3048 ?        Ss   18:48   0:00 sshd: [accepted]    
root       544  0.0  0.1  10216  2840 ?        Ss   16:46   0:00 dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
root         1  0.0  0.1  33504  2308 ?        Ss   16:46   0:01 /sbin/init
bitnami   2461  0.0  0.0 105640  1896 ?        S    18:43   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0  
root       900  0.0  0.0  61376  1696 ?        Ss   16:46   0:00 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the site had been hacked. I understand this is pretty common with wordpress.

Anyway we signed up for a plan with the nice folks at [WPEngine](http://wpengine.com). The site would run for just long enough to run their simple migration tool, and once they had it on their servers their impressive support kicked in.

The solution here is to avoid ever having to look after a wordpress installation. And if you really, really have to then learn a few things about wordpress and **lock it down**!